# How to make Kivy works with Pycharm on Windows 7? Stuck with Interpreter

Tags: python, pycharm, kivy

I'm doing this tutorial

https://github.com/kivy/kivy/wiki/Setting-Up-Kivy-with-various-popular-IDE's

and I have problem with this step:

> Add 2 new Python interpreters in PyCharm.
>
> - Bootstrapper: Choose the earlier created "python.bat" from the Kivy    package folder.
> - Project Interpreter: Choose the "python.exe" from the Python       subdirectory in the Kivy package folder.

There is no Python interpreters in settings. Only "Project Interpreter".

I looks like this: http://www.webpagescreenshot.info/i3/541987c5625182-01587273

Instead this: www.webpagescreenshot.info/i3/541984dcd3dd53-61170834

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PyCharm recently changed the structure of it's Settings dialogue. You should be able to set the python interpreter for your *entire* project by changing 'Project Interpreter'. However, if you wish to choose a specific interpreter for each configuration, you can open the 'Run/Debug Configurations' dialog (usually can find it from the drop down of scripts on the top toolbar, go to 'Edit Configurations..'